# Collect number of unique property values in Swift array of objects

Tags: swift, functional-programming

Say I have a simple `Ingredient` class:

```
class Ingredient {
    let section : String // 'Produce', 'Spices', 'Dairy', 'Grains'
}
```

And I have a pile of `Ingredient` items:

```
var ingredients : [Ingredient] = ...
```

I want to collect the **number of distinct sections from these ingredients**.

I can do this in Java via (relying on the auto-clumping of `Set` types):

```
ingredients.stream().map(Ingredient::getSection).collect(Collectors.toSet()).count()
```

Or, using the `distinct()` method:

```
ingredients.stream().map(Ingredient::getSection).distinct().count()
```

But **I'm looking for** a way to do a similar one-liner in Swift. Some of the research I've done shows people writing their own methods to collect distinct values, but I was hoping there would be a `distinct()` or `Set`-collecting method for Swift types.

Comment: This looks more like reactive programming

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you can do this in much the same way by mapping over your ingredients array to extract an array of sections – you can then convert these to a `Set` and get out the count, giving you the number of distinct sections.

```
let distinctSections = Set(ingredients.map{$0.section}).count
```

Answer (score 4):

It's the same mostly, you should use the `Set` type:

```
let ingredients = [Ingredient(section: "Produce"), Ingredient(section: "Produce"), Ingredient(section: "Spices"), Ingredient(section: "Dairy")]

let sections = Set(ingredients.map{ $0.section })
let numDistinctSections = Set(ingredients.map{ $0.section }).count
```

Also, nothing simpler than declaring your own `distinct` function:

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element : Hashable {
    func distinct() -> [Generator.Element] {
        return Array(Set(self))
    }
}

let sections = ingredients.map{ $0.section }.distinct()
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Turn your sections into a `[String]`, use that to create a `Set` and get the count like this:

```
let numUnique = Set(ingredients.map({ $0.section })).count
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Swift 3, and keeping O(n) complexity it looks like this:

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {

    func distinct() -> Array<Element> {
        return Array(Set(self))
    }
}
```